# Output the last few characters of a string - PHP / Yii

Tags: php, yii

How do I output just the last 3 characters of *docno* below? This docno outputs a really long string of numbers, and I wanted to simplify it to make it look cleaner by just showing the last 3 digits.

```
Yii::$app->reporter->col((isset($data[0]['docno'])? $data[0]['docno']:''),'300',null,false,'1px solid ','','L','Helvetica','11','','','').'<br />';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [substr()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

As documentation said:

> If start is non-negative, the returned string will start at the
>   start'th position in string, counting from zero. For instance, in the
>   string 'abcdef', the character at position 0 is 'a', the character at
>   position 2 is 'c', and so forth.
>
> If start is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th
>   character from the end of string.

So use negative value in second parameter

```
$data[0]['docno'] = substr($data[0]['docno'], -3);
```

Now use this in your `Yii::$app->.....` line

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) with a negative number in the 2nd argument.

```
$shortenedDocNo = substr($data[0]['docno'], -3);
```

From the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

> `string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`
>
> **If start is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th character from the end of string.**